# How to implement jQuery drag and drop function in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, drag-and-drop

I am new to jQuery drag and drop functions. And when I am trying to implement a small example in mvc4 I am getting an error like:

> resizable method is not available

Can any one help me?

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    #resizediv { 
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 0.5em;
        background:#EB5E00;
        color:#fff
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#resizediv").resizable({});
        $("#resizediv").draggable({});
    });
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="resizediv" class="ui-widget-content">
        Move... or Resize....<br />Things will go....
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i am getting error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'resizable'

Comment: Press CTRL + SHIFT + I then click the Network Tab, Reload your page. Any file name resource titles that are RED in colour are indications the resource could not be found because it's path is incorrect or the resource is missing.

Comment: i checked twice in network tab.all resources are loding correctly.. and no one are in red color.

Comment: just now i found a small mistake i have done due to that i am getting error: that is in layout page already jquery advance reference i have added once i remove that .problem is fixed

Comment: good. you should debug the problem once it comes.

Comment: This question helped me so I want to add my little bit here. I had the "@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")" line in my _Layout.cshtml twice. I added one up at the top and then added jQuery UI up top too. The second render call to jQuery hosed everything. When I removed it, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

jquery draggable and droppable functions are

$('selector').draggable({ option: value });
$('selector').droppable({ option: value });